# undefined reference to symbol '_ZN3ros10NodeHandle9subscribeERNS_16SubscribeOptionsE'

Tags: c++, cmake, ros

I am simply trying to compile a program in ROS. I already linked all the necessary libraries but this one I can't find. All I am getting is the following error in code blocks (also in eclipse).

Anybody know how to get rid of this error? Or even which library it require?

```
/usr/bin/ld:CMakeFiles/DistanceKinectDemo.dir/src/DistanceKinectDemo.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol

'_ZN3ros10NodeHandle9subscribeERNS_16SubscribeOptionsE'

/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libroscpp.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gpuvoxelgetpointcloud/CMakeFiles/DistanceKinectDemo.dir/build.make:370: recipe for target 
'/home/pcl_gpu/devel/lib/gpuvoxelgetpointcloud/DistanceKinectDemo' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/shupeng/pcl_gpu/devel/lib/gpuvoxelgetpointcloud/DistanceKinectDemo] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1130: recipe for target 'gpuvoxelgetpointcloud/CMakeFiles/DistanceKinectDemo.dir/all' failed
```

Comment: You are probably missing some link command in the CMakeLists.txt. Please edit your question to add the content of the CMakeLists.txt of your package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linker cannot find the symbol in the list of libraries.
When calling `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...`, there has to be the component `roscpp` listed. Furthermore, you need to add `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` to your `target_link_libraries` call.
Finally, the libraries for linking should be listed in descending order regarding there dependencies, which means that you should put `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` in the end of the `target_link_libraries` call if you have other libraries depending on it.
In the end, your `CMakeLists.txt` file should look like this:

```
...
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp <more packages>)
...
add_executable(DistanceKinectDemo <your cpp files>)
...
target_link_libraries(DistanceKinectDemo
<all your libraries and other dependencies>
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Comment: the problem isfind_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp <more packages>) .there are a few models.